# Jackson Deserialize Integer Converting Error

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to handle if required filed comes with a String value while I expect it as Integer. For example;

```
{
"transactionTimeMilliseconds": "asd"
}
```

but it defined as int in Java code.

```
private int transactionTimeMilliseconds;
@JsonCreator
public Channel(@JsonProperty("transactionTimeMilliseconds") int transactionTimeMilliseconds) { 
        this.transactionTimeMilliseconds = transactionTimeMilliseconds;
    }
```

I have an exception informer class.

## CLASS

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionConfiguration extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MismatchedInputException.class) // Or whatever exception type you want to handle
    public ResponseEntity<JsonException> handleMissingFieldError(MismatchedInputException exception) { // Or whatever exception type you want to handle
        int code = 601;
        String message = exception.getMessage().split("\n")[0] + exception.getMessage().split(";")[1].replace("]", "");
        JsonException jsonException = new JsonException(code,message);
        return ResponseEntity.status(jsonException.getCode()).body(jsonException);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(UnrecognizedPropertyException.class) // Or whatever exception type you want to handle
    public ResponseEntity<JsonException> handleUnrecognizedFieldError(UnrecognizedPropertyException exception) { // Or whatever exception type you want to handle
        int code = 602;
        String message = exception.getMessage().split(",")[0] + exception.getMessage().split(";")[1].replace("]", "");
        JsonException jsonException = new JsonException(code,message);
        return ResponseEntity.status(jsonException.getCode()).body(jsonException);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(JsonParseException.class) // Or whatever exception type you want to handle
    public ResponseEntity<JsonException> handleJsonParseError(JsonParseException exception) {
        int code = 603;
        String message = exception.getMessage().split(":")[0] + exception.getMessage().split(";")[1].replace("]", "");
        JsonException jsonException = new JsonException(code,message);
        return ResponseEntity.status(jsonException.getCode()).body(jsonException);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(InvalidFormatException.class) // Or whatever exception type you want to handle
    public ResponseEntity<JsonException> handleJsonInvalidFormatError(InvalidFormatException exception) {
        int code = 604;
        String message = exception.getMessage().split(":")[0] + exception.getMessage().split(";")[1].replace("]", "");
        JsonException jsonException = new JsonException(code,message);
        return ResponseEntity.status(jsonException.getCode()).body(jsonException);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(JsonMappingException.class) // Or whatever exception type you want to handle
    public ResponseEntity<JsonException> handleNullFieldError(JsonMappingException exception) {
        int code = 605;
        String message = exception.getMessage().split(":")[0] + exception.getMessage().split(";")[1].replace("]", "");
        JsonException jsonException = new JsonException(code,message);
        return ResponseEntity.status(jsonException.getCode()).body(jsonException);
    }
}
```

I have to recognize that value, and if this field is wrong as written in above, set it default value as 0.

Should I write a custom deserializer to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

something like this worked for me :

```
class Val {
    private int v;

    public int getV() {
        return v;
    }

    @JsonSetter // or  @JsonProperty("v")
    public void setV(String v) {
        System.out.println("in setter");
        try {
           this.v = Integer.parseInt(v);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.v = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void test() throws IOException {
    String json = " { \"v\" : 1 } ";
    Val v = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Val.class);
    System.out.println(v.getV()); // prints 1

    json = " { \"v\" : \"asd\" } ";
    v = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Val.class);
    System.out.println(v.getV()); // prints 0
}
```

I tried something like this but couldn't get it to work so far.

```
class Val {
    private int v;

    @JsonCreator
    public Val(@JsonProperty("v") String v) {
        System.out.println("in setter");
        try {
           this.v = Integer.parseInt(v);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.v = 0;
        }
    }

    public int getV() {
        return v;
    }
}
```